# Physical interpretation of diffeomorphism from $SO(3)$ to $\mathbb R \mathbb P^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, rotation

I am not good at picturing either $SO(3)$ or $\mathbb R \mathbb P^3$, the latter denoting the real projective space.

Can someone give me a rough physical understanding of the geometry and implication of the fact that $SO(3)$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R \mathbb P^3$?

What does this imply for the rotation matrices? What are these rotation matrices in $\mathbb R \mathbb P^3$

Is there a lower dimension analogy to this fact?

Comment: Why do you believe there *is* a physical interpretation of that fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements of the projective space $\Bbb R\Bbb P^3$ are 1-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$. The unit sphere $S^3$ in $\Bbb R^4$ will intersect each of these in exactly two antipodal points, from which it is easily seen that $\Bbb R\Bbb P^3$ can be realized as $S^3$ with antipodal points identified. Now $S^3$ can also be realized as the space of unit quaternions, and these can actually be seen to [define rotations of $\Bbb R^3$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). It is not hard to see that unit quaternions $q$ and $-q$ define the same rotation (namely over $\theta$ and over $\theta + 2\pi$ about the same axis).

Comment: Hi can an analogy be made between $RP^2$ and $R^3$? and how would you visualize that? Could you please also briefly define antipodal points and what you mean by $RP^3$ can be realized as $S^3$ with antipodal points, thanks

Comment: In general the points of $\Bbb R\Bbb P^n$ are the 1-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, and can be identified with points of $S^n$ with antipodal points identified (also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space); antipodal points are simply points on the sphere that are connected by a line through the origin. $S^3$ with these points pairwise identified means a new space whose points are these pairs. You may want to look at the definition of a quotient space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28topology%29